# Multiple LUIS models from config

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I use 2 LUIS models in 1 LUIS Dialog via attributes

```
[LuisModel("model1", "")]    
[LuisModel("model2", "")]
[Serializable]
public class LuisDialog
```

I need to get these models from the config file.
In Autofac I can only register 1

```
builder.Register(c => new LuisModelAttribute("model1", ""))...
```

How can I set up multiple Luis models from a config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will work since the `LuisModel` is being injected to the `LuisService` you are registering (which probably is the next line in your configuration) and the LuisService is just expecting a single model and not an array of them.

The way I can think this could work is, instead of registering the model(s) to the `Autofac` container, you should register multiple `LuisService` defining the value of the model parameter of the constructor to each of your models (see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/LuisService.cs#L225)).

In that way, when you resolve your `LuisDialog` based dialog, it will inject multiple `ILuisService` (see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L160)) as it's prepared to receive an array of services.

I haven't tried this, but you could see if something like this works:

```
var model1 = new LuisModelAttribute("model1", "");
var model2 = new LuisModelAttribute("model2", "");

builder.RegisterType<LuisService>()
       .WithParameter("model", model1)
       .Keyed<ILuisService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .SingleInstance(); or // .InstancePerLifetimeScope()

builder.RegisterType<LuisService>()
       .WithParameter("model", model2)
       .Keyed<ILuisService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .SingleInstance(); or // .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
```

Alternatively, you can use `RegisterInstance` and register the instances of the `LuisService` with their specific model.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the question; not sure why unnaccepted the answer when the issue is out of the scope.